# Computing 3SUM problem in $O(n\lg n) + \frac{n^2}{4}$ time

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

I've constructed an algorithm that solves the 3SUM problem in $O(n\lg n) + \frac{n^2}{4}$ time. I'm new to algorithms and was wondering how good is my running time? Googling didn't help.
thanks..

Comment: Since you are optimizing constant factors, you might want to edit the question to give the precise statement of the version of 3SUM that you are considering and your definition of $n$, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also, please specify precisely which operations you're counting.

Comment: why are you not including the entire complexity estimate in $O(f(n))$?

Answer (score 4):

There are known algorithms that take strictly less than $O(n^2)$ time (i.e., they run in $o(n^2)$ time), under certain theoretical computational models.  See, e.g.,

- [Subquadratic Algorithms for 3SUM](http://www.mit.edu/~ibaran/papers/3sum.pdf).  Ilya Baran, Erik D. Demaine, Mihai Patrascu.

However, it is not clear to me whether this leads to a practical improvement in real implementations.

Did you do a literature search for work on the 3SUM problem?  The above paper immediately comes up as soon as you search for "3SUM" on Google Scholar.  On this site, we expect you to do your own research first before asking here, and to show what you've tried in your question.  Please make sure to read the [help center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how this site works.  You might want to do a literature search, including reading the relevant references cited in the paper above, then editing your question to reflect this research -- or adding an answer to answer your own question.

Comment: There is now a [subquadratic 3SUM algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0799) which doesn't use bit-fiddling.